# Part of Data get lost on adding to session and commiting flask

Tags: python, mysql, session, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

The model is

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    artistname = db.Column(db.String(64))
    photourl = db.Column(db.String(1000))
    contactInfo = db.Column(db.String(20))
    description = db.Column(db.String(500))
    date = db.Column(db.Date)
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % (self.photourl)
```

Here photourl is the url of photos posted.

After form submission.

```
user = User(artistname = form.artist.data,photourl = "",
            description = form.description.data,contactInfo = form.contactinfo.data,date = datetime.datetime.utcnow().date() )
```

I add all the details without photourl.

Now i make list of all the filenames which is stored in **filename** variable in below code.And join with * in middle.

```
filename = "*".join(filename)
print(filename)
```

The sample output appeared in terminal of printed filename is

```
mic16.jpg*nepal_earthquake_death6.png
```

After combining all the filenames. I store it in database by.

```
user.photourl = filename
print(user)
db.session.add(user)
db.session.commit()
```

Here printed output of user in terminal is

```
<User u'mic16.jpg*nepal_earthquake_death6.png'>
```

which shows that infomation is loaded correctly.

Now when I do **db.session.add(user) followed by db.session.commit().** In **user table of the database under photourl column only mic16.jpg part is stored and rest of the part is ommited** i.e. part before * is stored.

There is no entry in the database.My database if a MYSQL database and using phpmyadmin. I am reading the database by using.

```
posts = User.query.order_by(User.date.desc()).limit(5).all()
photourls = []
for i in posts:
    photourls.append(i.photourl.split('*'))
```

Required urls are to be in the photourls. But only a **single url  is present** for each post.

I am just out of my mind and don't have clue of whats going on?

Comment: Have you tried with something else than `*` ?

Comment: yes first I tried with , then I went on to *

Comment: How did u read back from database?..Can u post the code for that? with output..

Comment: I have edited the post and added how I read the database. However, in the database table itself I cannot find the later part of the url. I.e. the part after *

Comment: Can try to replace `*` with some other char like `S` ..

Comment: Yes I can replace it with some other char Like S. THis way there is no problem. But won't it create bugs in future where Somehow if the filename and S is matched

Comment: When I replaces with The letter S it worked But I used XYZAB and then it stopped working again. I don't know what is happening?

Comment: are you running a windows os?

Comment: no I running on ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the size of your photourl string, you want to save several image filenames inside a string separated by an asterisk *. A better alternative would be storing the filenames in a JSON array with each filename as a string.

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    artistname = db.Column(db.String(64))
    photourls = db.Column(JSON)
```

You can use [getlist](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.getlist) to upload several image files at once.

```
def upload():
    uploaded_images = flask.request.files.getlist("file")
```

The JSON would be stored as shown below.

```
{
    "photourls":["mic16.jpg", "nepal_earthquake_death6.png"]
}
```